# redis remote connection successful，but can't get data

Tags: redis, remote-server

I wanted to see the data saved on a remote server.
I had annotated the bing IP and restarted redis server.
[redis.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8d8R.png)

I seted "a" "b" on remote redis:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26fhU.png)

Connection message shows as follow:
[redis-desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Tlq.png)
[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88jfS.png)

My client is window7 and redis desktop manager 0.9.0.760
Remote server is Debian 7 x64 and redis server version 2.4.14.

How can I see the data by client redis desktop manager?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `get a` maybe? `keys *` maybe?

Comment: Thanks,I had solved it on anther ubuntu16 server.